# Gimp doesn't start: gimp: symbol lookup error

Tags: gimp

Debian stretch Kde.

Gimp doesn't start. At trying using terminal I get:

```
gimp: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgegl-0.4.so.0: undefined symbol: babl_format_with_space
```

thanks...

Comment: You have a bad build or you haven't installed it correctly.

Comment: Make sure your Debian is compatible with Gimp 2.10. On the Ubuntu side, IIRC you need at least Ubuntu 17.10 to run Gimp 2.10 natively. Otherwise you can find [flatpak packages](https://github.com/flathub/org.gimp.GIMP) to run Gimp 2.10 on earlier Linux versions.